# Node location in parent space

Tags: javafx

I'm searching for a way to calculate the position of a deep child node in a parent node. The following code is my first draft which does not work correctly. It sums up the `layout*Property` by recursivly working up the node tree from the target node until the matching parent is found. But the calculated positions are always off. Am I missing something?

```
  public static Pair<DoubleBinding, DoubleBinding> getNodeLocationInParentSpace(
        Node node, Parent parent )
  {
     DoubleBinding x = node.layoutXProperty().add( 0 );
     DoubleBinding y = node.layoutYProperty().add( 0 );

     return getNodeLocationInParentSpace( node, parent, x, y );
  }

  public static Pair<DoubleBinding, DoubleBinding> getNodeLocationInParentSpace(
        Node node, Parent parent, DoubleBinding x, DoubleBinding y )
  {
     if( node == parent )
     {
        return new Pair<DoubleBinding, DoubleBinding>( x, y );
     }
     else
     {
        return getNodeLocationInParentSpace( node.getParent(), parent,
              x.add( node.layoutXProperty() ), 
              y.add( node.layoutYProperty() ) );
     }
  }
```

The scenario is that I have a `Pane` which contains dragable nodes. I want to create a visual connection between such nodes with a `Curve`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only on a whim I found the problem. My custom nodes extend layout container like `HBox` or `VBox`. They are included in the node tree twice as the custom class and then as the container class. By filtering the custom nodes out the positions are now spot on.

```
     if( node instanceof Pane )
     {
        return getNodeLocationInParentSpace( node.getParent(), parent,
              x.add( node.layoutXProperty() ),
              y.add( node.layoutYProperty() ) );
     }
     else
     {
        return getNodeLocationInParentSpace( node.getParent(), parent, x, y );
     }
```